Air conditioner condenser pad over rocky, uneven ground

Wanting to pour a small pad for a side discharge AC compressor under my deck. The ground as shown is never level and hard rock. Unit is 200 lbs and I need this pad to last 10-12 years.
I am considering whether it’s worth leveling the area out with a breaker tool or just cleaning and pouring over the top.
Should I drill into the rock and drop some rebar in? Plan to use wire mesh horizontally. Any good solution for the low spot - gravel or just pour the concrete thick?
Thanks for your advice!

just level with concrete, minimum thickness 2.5 inch

I hope you also planned to make sure it can properly vent,

You'd be surprised what is OK for a heat pump or A/C. I've seen plenty of mini split outdoor units installed under decks and working great.

going from your picture putting an AC condenser in such a location which looks fairly enclosed is not a smart idea.  The harder it is to install and service in the future the more problems you will have, not to mention the noise that will likely resonate up into the deck and then into the house, not to mention the lack of heat removal being in an enclosed space.

Assuming it looks more tilted than it actually is, clean the area, build a form, and pour some concrete. For bonus points you can make a piece of cardboard with bolts already in it to squish down into the concrete so you have a ready to go spot to bolt the AC down.
If it is actually very tilted, you'll probably want to drill and mortar in some anchors before you pour the concrete. If you're in an earthquake area, you might want to do this regardless.

if it's very tilted you could use a power hammer to knock down some of the high spots
